# Redirect a URL containing specified folder or directory to php file

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have a folder called `myfolder` and I want to redirect to `myphpfile.php` if someone requests a URL containing `myfolder`.

Example URL:

```
http://mydomain.com/myfolder/for-test.html
```

I wrote an `.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^myfolder/.* /myphpfile.php [QSA]
</IfModule>
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: I have test and you config work :(

Comment: sorry.... "myfolder" is a virtual directory...